# Is passing username/password in http string safe for this API?

Tags: security, https

Reading over 
http://getpocket.com/api/docs/

Is it safe to pass a password through the HTTP string? My understand is that this is not safe, even though it's HTTPS. Correct?

Comment: The data, including the URL with any query parameters, will be encrypted.  But I look at an API design like that and pinch my nose anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation states that you're passing over HTTPS.  Actually all of the information whether GET or POST in the HTTP Header is part of the SSL Transport therefore the URL parameters are encrypted as well, so your GET parameters are encrypted.  What can't be guaranteed is what your client will retain.  Or if there was some other process that exposed some information such as when your server did a DNS lookup for the host name.  Another example is if you have a browser and it keeps a history of everything you type in it including your https urls then you may compromise your security.

Below is the HTTP Header, your client will initiate a TCP connection and send something like the following:

```
GET /tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/ HTTP/1.1  
Host: net.tutsplus.com  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)  
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate  
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7  
Keep-Alive: 300  
Connection: keep-alive  
Cookie: PHPSESSID=r2t5uvjq435r4q7ib3vtdjq120  
Pragma: no-cache  
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

SSL will dictate that all that information is encrypted along with anything that is sent back.  I would say you're safe using this API, the only difference between the GET and the POST methods would be that in the POST the parameters would be in the body whereas with the GET the parameters are in the header.  In both cases all the sensitive information is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

I agree in principle that it sounds unsafe.  URLs can end up in all kinds of funny places in plain text (even over HTTPS), like logs.  It would be best to avoid having it in plaintext anywhere.

You should probably talk to the API authors about whether there is an alternative strategy.  For example, it looks like some of those methods support both POST and GET, in which case you could possibly POST password details, which is a relatively safe thing to do over an HTTPS connection.